# Seeking CMS option for heavily customized dashboard site?

Tags: content-management-system

I'm currently developing a dashboard system full of web apps that utilize jQuery, AJAX, and PHP heavily. I frequently update this system with new apps that are highly customized and designed to be customizable. I prefer coding things from scratch because I like the freedom of writing clean code that isn't dependent on foreign plug-ins (the authors of which I oftentimes don't know personally) or code that is tangled up in pre-built architectures (i.e. Wordpress AJAX backend calls).

I have a fully functioning site that works. I'm achieving the analytics and functionality I've set out to develop so far. However, it's been brought to my attention to consider utilizing a CMS like Drupal or Joomla or Wordpress as the site gets larger and supports more users, so that it's as future proof as possible. I've tried Wordpress in the past. I'm not a fan. It feels too restricting. I'm looking for a CMS that support a Dashboard system where I'm free to code without relying on plug-ins or backend libraries . Ideally, something like Wordpress but without plug-ins and a frustrating backend.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco is good, it's fully customisable and open-source. I've used it multiple times. It starts off bare-bones and you have to build most things from the ground up, however it does come with a fairly sizable online community.

As it's written in Angular, you can change the CMS HTML pages on the fly, and I find it a little more forgiving than some CMS' such as Orchard.